Animated TV Special featuring distinctive opening theme
It was an animated program from the 80-early 90s. 
It was a TV special. Not an actual series. Like a Saturday morning type of thing.
The characters were these weird, but cute, looking creatures, that all had something to do with zodiac signs (Leo, Sagittarius, Scorpio, Pisces, etc). And their names were a play on those signs.
They were on some kind of mission. I think it had something to do with birthdays.
What I remember most is the opening theme. It had a specific tune. The lyrics "Happy birthday to you. Happy birthday to you. Happy Birthday. May al your dreams and wishes come true. Happy birthday to you." But it wasn't in the tune of the traditional happy birthday song. 

Most probably it's Star Street: The Adventures of the Star Kids.

Star Street is a Dutch children's cartoon that was popular both in
  Benelux and in the United Kingdom. The protagonists were pink
  big-nosed creatures comically fashioned after horoscopes of the
  western zodiac and was set on a small star-shaped planet in the outer
  reaches of the universe.

It is a series, not a TV special, but since the lyrics of the song that can be heard at the end of the first episode are almost identical to the ones from your question I think this is what you're after.
